# Mysql Pivot View

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, pivot

I have a mysql table as below

```
username    interval    totalmails
User1      10:00            3
User2      10:00            1
User3      10:00            1
User6      10:00            4
User7      10:00            4
User8      10:00            5
User9      10:00            2
User10     10:00            5
User2      11:00            4
User3      11:00            7
User5      11:00            4
User6      11:00            4
User8      11:00            4
User9      11:00            3
User4      9:00             9
User5      9:00             1
User7      9:00             7
User8      9:00             3
```

I am looking for a pivot view which would output as below:

```
Username       9:00        10:00      11:00      Grand Total
 User1                       3                       3
 User2                       1           4           5
 User3                       1           7           8
 User4           9                                   9
 User5           1                       4           5
 User6                       4           4           8
 User7           7           4                      11
 User8           3           5           4          12
 User9                       2           3           5
 Grand Total    20          25          26          71
```

Can this be done by one mysql query without using prepare and execute ?

Probably a select query

Currently i am doing it with php. below is mycode:

```
$data = array();
            $d    = array();
            $heading = array('Username');
            $c    = array('Grand Total' => 0);
            //$data['usernames']['username'] = 'Username';

            foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
                $data['tbl'][$value['username']][strtotime($value['interval'])] = $value['mails'];
                $data['tbl']['Grand Total'][strtotime($value['interval'])]      = ($data['tbl']['Grand Total'][strtotime($value['interval'])] + $value['mails']);
                //$data['tbl']['Grand Total']['Grand Total']                         = ($data['tbl']['Grand Total']['Grand Total'] + $value['mails'])/2;
                $data['intervals'][strtotime($value['interval'])] = $value['interval'];
                $data['usernames'][$value['username']]            = $value['username'];
            }

            foreach ($data['tbl'] as $key => $value) {
                $data['tbl'][$key]['Grand Total'] = array_sum($value);
            }

            //$data['tbl'] = array_merge($data['tbl'], $d);
            //$data['tbl'] = array_merge($data['tbl'], $c);
            array_unique($data['intervals']);
            array_unique($data['usernames']);
            ksort($data['intervals']);
            $data['intervals']['Grand Total'] = 'Grand Total';
            $data['usernames']['Grand Total'] = 'Grand Total';

            $this->load->library('table');
            $tmpl = array(
                'table_open'         => '<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" id="sent_tbl">',
                'heading_row_start'  => '<tr>',
                'heading_row_end'    => '</tr>',
                'heading_cell_start' => '<th style="text-align: center;">',
                'heading_cell_end'   => '</th>',
                'row_start'          => '<tr class="odd gradeX">',
                'row_end'            => '</tr>',
                'cell_start'         => '<td style="text-align: center;">',
                'cell_end'           => '</td>',
                'row_alt_start'      => '<tr class="odd gradeX">',
                'row_alt_end'        => '</tr>',
                'cell_alt_start'     => '<td style="text-align: center;">',
                'cell_alt_end'       => '</td>',
                'table_close'        => '</table>'
            );
            $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
            $heading = array_merge($heading,array_values($data['intervals']));

            $this->table->set_heading($heading);

            foreach ($data['usernames'] as $uname => $unameval) {
                $row = array();
                $row = array(array('data'  => $unameval,
                                   'style' => 'text-align:left;'
                )
                );

                if (strlen($unameval) > 1) {
                    foreach ($data['intervals'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($data['tbl'][$unameval][$key] > 0) {
                            array_push($row, round($data['tbl'][$unameval][$key], 1));
                        } else {
                            array_push($row, '');
                        }
                    }
                }

                //echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, TRUE) . '</pre>';

                $this->table->add_row($row);
            }

            echo '<strong>Hourly Total:</strong>';
            echo $this->table->generate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
function get()
 {
  $this->db->select("username,
    Avg(CASE WHEN interval ='10:00' THEN totalmail END) as [10:00],
    Avg(CASE WHEN interval ='11:00' THEN totalmail) END as [11:00],
    Avg(CASE WHEN interval ='12:00' THEN totalmail) END as [12:00],
    Sum(CASE WHEN interval ='10:00' THEN totalmail) END as [Grand_Total];


$this->db->from('your_table_name');
$this->db->group_by('username');

}
```

hope this will work for you...!!!

do let me know: thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `interval` = ''',
      `interval`,
      ''' then totalmails END) AS `',
      `interval`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT username, ', @sql, '
                  ,SUM(totalmails) AS Grand FROM Table1 
                   GROUP BY username 
                   UNION
                   SELECT ''Grand Total'' AS Username, ', @sql, '
                  ,SUM(totalmails) AS totalmails
                   FROM Table1
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
╔═════════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  USERNAME   ║ 10:00  ║ 11:00  ║  9:00  ║ GRAND ║
╠═════════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ User1       ║ 3      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║     3 ║
║ User10      ║ 5      ║ (null) ║ (null) ║     5 ║
║ User2       ║ 1      ║ 4      ║ (null) ║     5 ║
║ User3       ║ 1      ║ 7      ║ (null) ║     8 ║
║ User4       ║ (null) ║ (null) ║ 9      ║     9 ║
║ User5       ║ (null) ║ 4      ║ 1      ║     5 ║
║ User6       ║ 4      ║ 4      ║ (null) ║     8 ║
║ User7       ║ 4      ║ (null) ║ 7      ║    11 ║
║ User8       ║ 5      ║ 4      ║ 3      ║    12 ║
║ User9       ║ 2      ║ 3      ║ (null) ║     5 ║
║ Grand Total ║ 25     ║ 26     ║ 20     ║    71 ║
╚═════════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73a83/3)

Comment: Hi hims056, I'm not a MySQL expert, I have a SQL Server background, but your script worked fast and nicely good to my dinamic columns pivot necessity. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielMelo : Glad to know that :)